# Computer not booting after changing power plan

Tags: windows, boot

I recently built a computer with an Aourus Motherboard and AMD CPU but I switched it to power saving mode and it instantly crashed. I shut down the computer (by holding the power button) and tried booting it up again. Accessing the BIOS and WinRE work fin, but if I just try to boot up on Windows as I normally would, it freezes on the spiral boot thing. I tried to reset power configuration options using cmd (in WinRE) but is had the error

```
X:\Windows\System32>powercfg -restoredefaultschemes
Not supported
```

I also tried to run control panel from cmd and it didn't work

```
X:\Windows\System32>control
X:\Windows\System32>control.exe
```

But a error dialog box appears. Accessing the `C:\` drive in general seems to not work

```
X:\Windows\System32>cd C:
X:\Windows\System32>
```

I don't know what to do, please help

Comment: Did you tried a chkdsk on drive C:?

Comment: It didn't do anything. I tried `sfc` `chkdsk`, I did anything I could do on cmd. I only got error results...

Comment: This happened to me as well... It seems that putting a computer that technically shouldn't have a power saving mode (because of the PSU) will crash windows since it doesn't know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you encounter something that you know caused an issue on your computer but can't fix it normally, try entering safe mode. You can do this in Windows Recovery (WinRE).

---

#### How to enter safe mode:

1. Get into WinRE, hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> while computer is starting/booting up. You can do this from restarting and holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, or powering on your laptop/desktop while holding <kbd>shift</kbd>
2. If there is a message saying something similar to

> Windows encountered an issue while booting
> or something similar to that (I don't remember exactly what it says), where there are two options, one which says `Restart` and the other that says `Advanced Options`, select `Advanced Options`

3. There will be things in the advanced options, one of which is `Startup Settings` (if you can't find it, look for more options/advanced options options)
4. If it prompts you to restart, click restart to change startup settings
5. Press <kbd>4</kbd> on your keyboard to enable safe mode or click the `Enable Safe mode` option
6. If prompted to restart, restart your computer.
7. The next boot will be in safe mode and should boot "correctly"

---

### What to do after entering safe mode:

- If you are looking for a specific app to change a setting (in your case control panel) just find it and use it as normal.
- With safe mode on, change necessary settings and use your computer as normal.
- Everything should be the same except your personalized things (i.e. Background, dark mode preference, lock screen image, resolution etc) if you boot up and can see your account it is working.
- There will be a watermark in the bottom corner that says `Safe Mode`

---

### Summary:

To fix your computer, enter safe mode and then change the necessary settings that you think went wrong. Then restart and try booting up again.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for your time

Comment: This worked, thank you... I was able to get out of power saving mode in Safe Mode...